# Determine optimal (recurring) frequency of discrete values

Tags: time-series, data-mining

So I'm trying to determine a semi-efficient way to calculate the optimal (recurring) frequency of a set of data. The data only exists at random time periods, but it is assumed that the data set is complete.

**For example:** Say that we had data recorded every time a movie was watched, for which the viewer recorded their liking of the movie. The likability obviously depends on what movie was watched. However, what I am interested in is the frequency at which movies should be watched for optimal likability. Furthermore, even if two movies were watched one after the other, and the viewer loved them, this should not be the optimal frequency unless:

1. it is proven that the viewer could continuously watch movies at that rate.
2. the data is not an outlier, and the results have been reproduced elsewhere in the data set.

How would one go about doing this? Note that in this scenario, the data could be processed as it was forming (we could tell the viewer to try watching movies at x frequency, for optimal results, but there is no guarantee that they will do it).

Thanks!